# Loop calling elements of a vector list

Tags: r, list, loops, vector

I have a data frame with some ambiguous observation names in it and want to add some classification to them. One of the problems I had was that some of the observation names match multiple classes that I would want to assign, so I decided to go for adding a column for each class and fill it with True/False depending on whether an observation relates to this class or not.

here is an example data frame:

```
col1 <- c(1:8)
col2 <- c("aa", "bb", "ab", "ba")
df <- data.frame(col1,col2)
```

so

```
   col1 col2
1     1   aa
2     2   bb
3     3   ab
4     4   ba
5     5   aa
6     6   bb
7     7   ab
8     8   ba
```

And the Class criteria vectors I have are:

```
Class1 <- "aa"                  # A Only
Class2 <- "bb"                  # B Only
Class3 <- c("ab", "ba")         # Diff symbols
Class4 <- c("ab", "ba", "aa")   # All A
Class5 <- c("ab", "ba", "bb")   # All B
```

I intended to resolve my problem with a loop that would at each turn populate a new column in data frame matching Col2 value to criteria in a respective vector.

```
Classes <- list(Class1, Class2, Class3, Class4, Class5)
ClassName <- c("A Only", "B Only", "Diff symbols", "All A", "All B")

for (i in 1:length(ClassName)){
    df[df$col2 %in% Classes[i], 2 + i] <- "x"
}
names(df)[3:7] <- ClassName
```

Now this is where the problem is - only length one vectors are working properly in the loop.

```
  col1 col2 A Only B Only Diff symbols All A All B
1    1   aa      x   <NA>         <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2    2   bb   <NA>      x         <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
3    3   ab   <NA>   <NA>         <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
4    4   ba   <NA>   <NA>         <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
5    5   aa      x   <NA>         <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
6    6   bb   <NA>      x         <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
7    7   ab   <NA>   <NA>         <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
8    8   ba   <NA>   <NA>         <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

Class3-Class5 produce no results for some reason, even thought if used outside loop they work fine - like:

```
df[df$col2 %in% Class3, 5] <- "x"

  col1 col2 A Only B Only Diff symbols All A All B
1    1   aa      x   <NA>         <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2    2   bb   <NA>      x         <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
3    3   ab   <NA>   <NA>            x  <NA>  <NA>
4    4   ba   <NA>   <NA>            x  <NA>  <NA>
5    5   aa      x   <NA>         <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
6    6   bb   <NA>      x         <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
7    7   ab   <NA>   <NA>            x  <NA>  <NA>
8    8   ba   <NA>   <NA>            x  <NA>  <NA>
```

I take it something is wrong with the way I use list but I cannot find an answer.

I would really appreciate somebody sharing an insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with how you use the brackets `[` and `[[` to index lists. Use `[` to return a new *list* with the selected index, `[[` to return *the object actually contained* at the selected index.

For example, using your code:

```
> Classes[1] # returns a list
[[1]]
[1] "ab" "ba"

> Classes[[1]] # returns a vector
[1] "ab" "ba"
```

By using the double-brackets, *i.e.*, changing your loop-code to:

```
for (i in 1:length(ClassName)) df[df$col2 %in% Classes[[i]], 2 + i] <- "x"
```

`df` changes to:

```
> df
  col1 col2 A Only B Only Diff symbols All A All B
1    1   aa   <NA>      x         <NA>     x  <NA>
2    2   bb   <NA>   <NA>            x  <NA>     x
3    3   ab      x      x            x  <NA>  <NA>
4    4   ba      x      x            x  <NA>  <NA>
5    5   aa   <NA>      x         <NA>     x  <NA>
6    6   bb   <NA>   <NA>            x  <NA>     x
7    7   ab      x      x            x  <NA>  <NA>
8    8   ba      x      x            x  <NA>  <NA>
```

Of course, there are other ways that might be more suited (e.g., easier to read) to doing what you want do do. For example:

```
df$contains.a <- grepl("a", df$col2)
```

Or if you want `x` or another value to mark a point:

```
df$contains.a <- ifelse(grepl("a", df$col2), "x", NA)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the advice! Your last suggestion works excellent as well int his case! Unfortunately I had multiple look-up patterns in the original work, so going for the lists was more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that the values in `Classes`  is a list, and using the single bracket operator (`[`) returns a list object, and not the object contained in a list.   It just so happens that the `%in%` operator does what you expect when the item contained in the list has one element (`Class1` for example), but not when the item in the list is longer (e.g. `Class3`).  Specifically, `df$col2 %in% Classes[i]` tests whether any of the elements of `df$col2` are equal to the members of `Classes[i]` which cannot be true with `Classes[[i]]` has length greater than 1.

The solution is that in this line `df[df$col2 %in% Classes[i], 2 + i] <- "x"`  you need to change `Classes[i]` to `Classes[[i]]`.

Comment: Hi. Many thanks for the reply this was exactly what I was looking for. I knew it must have been something simple I am missing